# Adding arrays with cython slower than numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, cython

I am just starting to learn cython, so please excuse my ignorance. Can cython improve on numpy for simply adding two arrays together? My very bad attempt at adding two arrays a + b to give a new array c is:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

DTYPE = np.int
ctypedef np.int_t DTYPE_t

def add_arrays(np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] a, np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] b, np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] c):
    cdef int x = a.shape[0]
    cdef int y = a.shape[1]
    cdef int val_a
    cdef int val_b
    for j in range(x):
        for k in range(y):
            val_a = a[j][k]
            val_b = b[j][k]
            c[j][k] = val_a + val_b    
    return c
```

However this version is 700 times slower (*edit: than numpy) when these arrays are passed:

```
n = 1000 
a = np.ones((n, n), dtype=np.int)
b = np.ones((n, n), dtype=np.int)
c = np.zeros((n, n), dtype=np.int)
```

I am obviously missing something very big.

Comment: Have you tried simply adding your two numpy arrays? table1 + table2 instead of all this indexing?

Comment: `nditer` is a better tool for iterating over the elements of one or more arrays in `cython`.  But numpy `a+b` is probably already using that in its C implementation of `__add__`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you are indexing the 2-D array like `c[j][k]` when actually you should do `c[j,k]`, otherwise Cython is using an intermediate buffer for `buf=c[j]`, from which it will take `buf[k]`, causing the slow-down. You should use this proper indexing plus the `cdef` declarations especified by @XavierCombelle.

You can check that this intermediate buffer is causing the slow-down by doing:

```
np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=1] buf
```

and then, inside the loop:

```
buf = c[j]
buf[k] = val_a + val_b
```

this declared buffer should give the same speed (or close) than:

```
c[j,k] = val_a + val_b
```

Comment: Amazing! just changing [j][k] references to [j, k] results in a huge speed up; now the code is only about 3x slower than numpy

Answer (score 3):

I think you are missing

```
cdef int j
cdef int k
```

so your variable loop are python object not c ones

Answer (score 1):

Here are two examples:

The "numpy way"

```
%%timeit
table1 = np.ones((10,10))
table2 = np.ones((10,10))
result = np.zeros((10,10))
table1 + table2 

100000 loops, best of 3: 14.5 µs per loop
```

The looping over indices way

```
%%timeit
def add_arrays(ar1, ar2):
    for j in range(len(ar1)):
        for k in range(len(ar2)):
            val_a = ar1[j][k]
            val_b = ar2[j][k]
            result[j][k] = val_a + val_b    
    return result

add_arrays(table1, table2)

1000 loops, best of 3: 307 µs per loop
```

Same thing, 20 times faster.

With all this, I am aware that I have not completely answered your question, but maybe it gives you a better perspective for your comparisons?

[edit] for 1000x1000 tables, the time difference is more pronounced; I supect is is due to the amortization of the overhead of building the tables.

```
former code: 100 loops, best of 3: 13.1 ms per loop
latter code: 1 loops, best of 3: 2.78 s per loop
```

Which is a 200 factor

Comment: do you mean 20 times slower pure python than numpy and he speaks about cython implementation

Comment: Good question, I should be more clear: I mean comparing using numpy as intended vs. looping over numpy arrays with indices. Based on the OP's suspicion that he was missing something, I wanted to help him calibrate where the real performance was before even venturing into cython territory.

Comment: Yes, it is, in principle........ however, it is an additional layer of complication that IMHO, should only be contemplated when other easier avenues have been exhausted; proper use of numpy is a great source of performance that is very often sufficient and easy to access.

Comment: Agreed numpy is great, I am just experimenting with cython!

Comment: Yeah, and this is great to experiment, I encourage you to do more of that. There is plenty to learn with tinkering :) I'am curious to see by how much a proper implementation of cython for this simple addition will beat numpy. (I have no experience with cython). Other things you could try are Numba and Jit, they are simpler to use than cython I am told.